# Why late init var cannot be used with Nullable?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

Why can't we use `lateinit` with nullable variables?

```
lateinit var v: String?
```

`lateinit` modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but if you think about it, if you'd allow that why would you make it `lateinit`? Just initialise it to `null`.

Comment: Look i know i will initialise it with some value but that will be a nullable value, on assigning that value to the variable we declared it will show a warning

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`lateinit` is only for avoid null checks in future, that's why `lateinit` modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types.

If you want it to be `nullable` then simply you can use like `var b: String? = null`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a variable of nullable type then you don't need late init . The doc says

> Normally, properties declared as having a non-null type must be initialized in the constructor.
>   However, fairly often this is not convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through
>   dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this case, you cannot supply a nonnull
>   initializer in the constructor, but you still want to avoid null checks when referencing the
>   property inside the body of a class.

So late init is intended to be used when you intend to initialize a variable somewhere not in the constructor and also want to avoid null checks.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation, `lateinit` specializes on non-nullable properties:

> Normally, properties declared as having a **non-null** type must be initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this case, you cannot supply a **non-null** initializer in the constructor, but **you still want to avoid null checks** when referencing the property inside the body of a class.

Also, if you take a look at the byte code of such a `lateinit` property, you see that the compiler adds a code block to ensure that this property has been initialized when being accessed. For `lateinit` properties, `null` indicates the properties initial but invalid state.

```
class WithLateInit {
    lateinit var something : String
}
```

becomes

```
public final class WithLateInit {
   @NotNull
   public String something;

   @NotNull
   public final String getSomething() {
      String var10000 = this.something;
      if (var10000 == null) { // <- here you can see the lateinit check
         Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("something");
      }

      return var10000;
   }

  //setter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Normally, properties declared as having a **non-null type** must be
>   initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not
>   convenient.
>
> For example, properties can be initialized through dependency
>   injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this case, you
>   cannot supply a **non-null initializer** in the constructor, but you
>   still want to avoid **null checks** when referencing the property
>   inside the body of a class.
>
> To handle this case, you can mark the property with the `lateinit`
>   modifier.

That's why it doesn't support **null**.

So, if you indicate any **var** as **lateinit** meaning compiler simply ignores it for initialization and mark it as **non-null type** that would be initialized in nearer future and is why it doesn't support nullable type to avoid runtime ambiguities.

Comment: Quote documentation (and other answer sources) instead of just copying it.

Answer (score 1):

> Kotlin's type system is aimed at eliminating the danger of null references from code

so both represent compromises. With [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) you ensure that the variable will eventually be initialized to non-null. If you cannot even guarantee that, you can use [nullable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types).

Answer (score 0):

One of the main feature in kotlin is Null Safe.

By default it won't allow u to create a null value. You have explicitly defined
 `var a: String? = null`
            , If u don't want to initialise any value to the variable there come "lateinit". While using lateinit variable You do pre-check whether it is initialised or not